# Dynamic memory allocation of arrays without calloc/malloc

Tags: c, arrays

I don't understand the array declaration in the following program:

```
int main(){
  int n;
  printf("How many numbers?");
  scanf(" %d",&n);
  int array['n'];
  for(int i = 0; i < n; i++)
  {
    scanf(" %d",&array[i]);
  }
  for(int i = 0; i < n; i++)
  {
    printf(" %d\n",*(array +i));
  }
  getch();
  return 0;
}
```

Comment: `int array['n'];` is nonsense

Answer (score 0, accepted):

well, the '' syntax means replace  with its ascii value. so

```
int array['n'];
```

is actually:

```
int array[110];
```

(as 'n'=110 in [ascii](http://www.asciitable.com/) )

so as long as n < 110 this will work, but I doubt that's what the coder intended !

likely `int array[n];` was the intention here. the lack of `malloc` means the array is created on the stack, not the heap. (further reading: [memory managment in c](http://staff.um.edu.mt/csta1/courses/lectures/csa2060/c8a.html) ).

the reason `int array['n'];` compiles while `int array[n];` does not is because array sizes need to be constatns. 'n' is a constant (110) while n is not.

EDIT: many users have noted this so I might as well spell it out, the constant array size restriction is compiler specific. modern pure c compilers allow it while c++ compilers do not. the question of [VLA](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Variable-length_array)'s being a good idea in general is a [matter of some debate](https://groups.google.com/forum/?fromgroups=#!topic/comp.std.c++/K_4lgA1JYeg)

Comment: Also, it does not create a VLA, which was what the question was about.

Comment: @Oren: Thanks for the concept, I got it.... Basically, it was not a dynamic array....

Comment: C arrays are not required to have constant size. That was true before C99, and is still true in C++.

Comment: Your wording is still misleading - it is not "compiler specific", except insomuch as it is compiler specific that a C compiler supports C, or that the user is even using a C compiler. The C language standard has supported variable-length arrays for 14 years now. The question is tagged with "C", not "C++", so it's fair to expect a conforming compiler, which **must** support VLAs.

Comment: @user4815162342 an answer to this question where the OP commented was deleted. the comment mentioned the compiler not accepting the VLA syntax, which is why I even bothered with it in my answer to begin with :) Also, trying to compile c code on a c++ compiler is not exactly unheard of..

Answer (score 1):

Replace `int array['n']` with `int array[n]` and make sure you're using a C compiler to compile the code, and it will work just fine. Auto-allocated arrays with non-constant size are called [VLA](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Variable-length_array) and were introduced in the C99, 14 years ago.

Answer (score 0):

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

// working in Dev-C++
int main() {
int a,i;

printf("enter size\n");
scanf("%d",&a);
int arr[a];
for(i=0;i<a;i++)
{
    scanf("%d",&arr[i]);
}
for(i=0;i<a;i++)
{
    printf("%d",arr[i]);
}
return 0;
}
```

Comment: Give explanation to your code, what you changed, added and so on. This will help the user to understand, and if correct, accept your answer.